# How do I play sounds from my iPad to my Stereo wirelessly?

Tags: ipad, audio

Is this possible to stream the audio played on an iPad to a Stereo wirelessly ?

My stereo is connected to my iMac via BlueTooth. So If I can play the audio from my iPad on my iMac this will do what I want. But maybe there is another way to do it...

Another question is : Can I transmit the sound to my mac using the simple connector cable ?

What I really want to do is to use for instance GarageBand and hear the sound on my stereo. Wirelessly would be the best, but, as a second choice, I can handle the fact to be forced to be connected with USB.

And please, I know the ultime and last choice to use the mini-jack output on the iPad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect the iPad directly to your stereo using bluetooth. Or you can use AirPlay to stream audo to your iMac. However you cannot record anything while doing this:

> While the "AirPlay - Bluetooth - HDMI" switch is on, an alert appears if you try to record an Audio Recorder or Guitar Amp Touch Instrument, or if you try to record a sound with the Sampler. You can turn the switch off from the alert.

From: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4622

Comment: <shame> OMG, I even didn't know that my iPad was bluetooth device! </shame>

Comment: You can AirPlay _to_ Macs? Cool!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to record via GarageBand on your iPad, then the only option currently is to connect it to your stereo using the minijack.

Comment: I don't want to record. I just want to play music without my headphone.

Comment: What is the model & make of your stereo?

Answer (score 0):

You can also stream iPad audio directly to a stereo, or amplified speakers, connected to an Airport Express or AppleTV 2.